# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$update_query' (T_VARIABLE) in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/tcetraveldesk/fetch.php on line 12

Tags: php, mysql

I am having an issue in this programming, I don't know what is the issue. I even checked with semicolons there is no issue regarding that

```html
<?php

include('includes/db.php');

if(isset($_POST['view'])){

// $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "notif");

if($_POST["view"] != '')

{
   $update_query = "UPDATE comments SET comment_status = 1 WHERE comment_status=0";
   mysqli_query($con, $update_query);
}
```

Comment: Missing a closing brace after the last line?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['view'])){ isn't closed.

Comment: the code has ending braces guys sry...even then it is not wrking